# For each row in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe, and for each row in that dataframe I have to do some complicated lookups and append some data to a file.

The dataFrame contains scientific results for selected wells from 96 well plates used in biological research so I want to do something like:

```
for (well in dataFrame) {
  wellName <- well$name    # string like "H1"
  plateName <- well$plate  # string like "plate67"
  wellID <- getWellID(wellName, plateName)
  cat(paste(wellID, well$value1, well$value2, sep=","), file=outputFile)
}
```

In my procedural world, I'd do something like:

```
for (row in dataFrame) {
    #look up stuff using data from the row
    #write stuff to the file
}
```

What is the "R way" to do this?

Comment: What is your question here?  A data.frame is a two-dimensional object and looping over the rows is a perfectly normal way of doing things as rows are commonly sets of 'observations' of the 'variables' in each column.

Comment: what I end up doing is: for (index in 1:nrow(dataFrame)) { row = dataFrame[index, ]; # do stuff with the row } which never seemed very pretty to me.

Comment: Does getWellID call a database or anything?  Otherwise, Jonathan is probably right and you could vectorize this.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can try this, using [`apply()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) function

```
> d
  name plate value1 value2
1    A    P1      1    100
2    B    P2      2    200
3    C    P3      3    300

> f <- function(x, output) {
 wellName <- x[1]
 plateName <- x[2]
 wellID <- 1
 print(paste(wellID, x[3], x[4], sep=","))
 cat(paste(wellID, x[3], x[4], sep=","), file= output, append = T, fill = T)
}

> apply(d, 1, f, output = 'outputfile')
```

Comment: Be careful, as the dataframe is converted to a matrix, and what you end up with (`x`) is a vector. This is why the above example has to use numeric indexes; the by() approach gives you a data.frame, which makes your code more robust.

Comment: did not work for me. The apply function treated every x given to f as a character value and not a row.

Comment: Note too that you can refer to the columns by name. So: `wellName <- x[1]` could also be `wellName <- x["name"]`.

Comment: When Darren mentioned robust, he meant something like shifting the orders of the columns. This answer would not work whereas the one with by() would still work.

Answer (score 131):

You can use the [`by()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html) function:

```
by(dataFrame, seq_len(nrow(dataFrame)), function(row) dostuff)
```

But iterating over the rows directly like this is rarely what you want to; you should try to vectorize instead.  Can I ask what the actual work in the loop is doing?

Comment: this will not work well if the data frame has 0 rows because `1:0` is not empty

Comment: Easy fix for the 0 row case is to use [seq_len()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html), insert `seq_len(nrow(dataFrame))` in place of `1:nrow(dataFrame)`.

Comment: How do you actually implement (row)?  Is it dataframe$column? dataframe[somevariableNamehere]?  How do you actually say its a row.  The pseudocode "function(row) dostuff" how would that actually look?

Comment: @Mike, change `dostuff` in this answer to `str(row)`  You'll see multiple lines printed in the console beginning with _" 'data.frame': 1 obs of x variables."_   But be careful, changing `dostuff` to `row` does not return a data.frame object for the outer function as a whole.  Instead it returns a list of one row data-frames.

Comment: Not everything should be vectorized. But in this case it would make sense I guess.

Comment: I fixed the issue noted by `sds` and `Jim` with an edit.

Answer (score 111):

First, Jonathan's point about vectorizing is correct.  If your getWellID() function is vectorized, then you can skip the loop and just use cat or write.csv:

```
write.csv(data.frame(wellid=getWellID(well$name, well$plate), 
         value1=well$value1, value2=well$value2), file=outputFile)
```

If getWellID() isn't vectorized, then Jonathan's recommendation of using `by` or knguyen's suggestion of `apply` should work.

Otherwise, if you really want to use `for`, you can do something like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dataFrame)) {
    row <- dataFrame[i,]
    # do stuff with row
}
```

You can also try to use the `foreach` package, although it requires you to become familiar with that syntax.  Here's a simple example:

```
library(foreach)
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
s <- foreach(d=iter(d, by='row'), .combine=rbind) %dopar% d
```

A final option is to use a function out of the `plyr` package, in which case the convention will be very similar to the apply function.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dataFrame, .(x), function(x) { # do stuff })
```

Comment: Shane, thank you.  I'm not sure how to write a vectorized getWellID.  What I need to do right now is to dig into an existing list of lists to look it up or pull it out of a database.

Comment: Feel free to post the getWellID question (i.e. can this function be vectorized?) separately, and I'm sure I (or someone else) will answer it.

Comment: Even if getWellID is not vectorized, I think you should go with this solution, and replace getWellId with `mapply(getWellId, well$name, well$plate)`.

Comment: Even if you pull it from a database, you can pull them all at once and then filter the result in R; that will be faster than an iterative function.

Comment: +1 for `foreach` - I'm going to use the hell out of that one.

Answer (score 32):

I think the best way to do this with basic R is:

```
for( i in rownames(df) )
   print(df[i, "column1"])
```

The advantage over the `for( i in 1:nrow(df))`-approach is that you do not get into trouble if `df` is empty and `nrow(df)=0`.

Answer (score 21):

I use this simple utility function:

```
rows = function(tab) lapply(
  seq_len(nrow(tab)),
  function(i) unclass(tab[i,,drop=F])
)
```

Or a faster, less clear form:

```
rows = function(x) lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) lapply(x,"[",i))
```

This function just splits a data.frame to a list of rows. Then you can make a normal "for" over this list:

```
tab = data.frame(x = 1:3, y=2:4, z=3:5)
for (A in rows(tab)) {
    print(A$x + A$y * A$z)
}
```

Your code from the question will work with a minimal modification:

```
for (well in rows(dataFrame)) {
  wellName <- well$name    # string like "H1"
  plateName <- well$plate  # string like "plate67"
  wellID <- getWellID(wellName, plateName)
  cat(paste(wellID, well$value1, well$value2, sep=","), file=outputFile)
}
```

Comment: It's faster to access a straight list then a data.frame.

Comment: Just realized it's even faster to make the same thing with double lapply: rows = function(x) lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) lapply(x,function(c) c[i]))

Comment: So the inner `lapply` iterates over the columns of the entire dataset `x`, giving each column the name `c`, and then extracting the `i`th entry from that column vector. Is this correct?

Comment: Very nice!  In my case, I had to convert from "factor" values to the underlying value: `wellName <- as.character(well$name)`.

Answer (score 11):

I was curious about the time performance of the non-vectorised options.
For this purpose, I have used the function f defined by knguyen

```
f <- function(x, output) {
  wellName <- x[1]
  plateName <- x[2]
  wellID <- 1
  print(paste(wellID, x[3], x[4], sep=","))
  cat(paste(wellID, x[3], x[4], sep=","), file= output, append = T, fill = T)
}
```

and a dataframe like the one in his example:

```
n = 100; #number of rows for the data frame
d <- data.frame( name = LETTERS[ sample.int( 25, n, replace=T ) ],
                  plate = paste0( "P", 1:n ),
                  value1 = 1:n,
                  value2 = (1:n)*10 )
```

I included two vectorised functions (for sure quicker than the others) in order to compare the cat() approach with a write.table() one...

```
library("ggplot2")
library( "microbenchmark" )
library( foreach )
library( iterators )

tm <- microbenchmark(S1 =
                       apply(d, 1, f, output = 'outputfile1'),
                     S2 = 
                       for(i in 1:nrow(d)) {
                         row <- d[i,]
                         # do stuff with row
                         f(row, 'outputfile2')
                       },
                     S3 = 
                       foreach(d1=iter(d, by='row'), .combine=rbind) %dopar% f(d1,"outputfile3"),
                     S4= {
                       print( paste(wellID=rep(1,n), d[,3], d[,4], sep=",") )
                       cat( paste(wellID=rep(1,n), d[,3], d[,4], sep=","), file= 'outputfile4', sep='\n',append=T, fill = F)                           
                     },
                     S5 = {
                       print( (paste(wellID=rep(1,n), d[,3], d[,4], sep=",")) )
                       write.table(data.frame(rep(1,n), d[,3], d[,4]), file='outputfile5', row.names=F, col.names=F, sep=",", append=T )
                     },
                     times=100L)
autoplot(tm)
```

The resulting image shows that apply gives the best performance for a non-vectorised version, whereas write.table() seems to outperform cat().
[image: ForEachRunningTime]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `by_row` function from the package `purrrlyr` for this:

```
myfn <- function(row) {
  #row is a tibble with one row, and the same 
  #number of columns as the original df
  #If you'd rather it be a list, you can use as.list(row)
}

purrrlyr::by_row(df, myfn)
```

By default, the returned value from `myfn` is put into a new [list column](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1) in the df called `.out`.

If this is the only output you desire, you could write `purrrlyr::by_row(df, myfn)$.out`

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you asked for R equivalent to other languages, I tried to do this. Seems to work though I haven't really looked at which technique is more efficient in R.

```
> myDf <- head(iris)
> myDf
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> nRowsDf <- nrow(myDf)
> for(i in 1:nRowsDf){
+ print(myDf[i,4])
+ }
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.4
```

For the categorical columns though, it would fetch you a Data Frame which you could typecast using as.character() if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something for a list object,

```
data("mtcars")
rownames(mtcars)
data <- list(mtcars ,mtcars, mtcars, mtcars);data

out1 <- NULL 
for(i in seq_along(data)) { 
  out1[[i]] <- data[[i]][rownames(data[[i]]) != "Volvo 142E", ] } 
out1
```

Or a data frame,

```
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars
out1 <- NULL 
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  row <- rownames(df[i,])
  # do stuff with row
  out1 <- df[rownames(df) != "Volvo 142E",]
  
}
out1
```