# How to read a json file line by line in R?

Tags: r, json, dataframe

Here is the raw `json` data:

```
json_file <-  '{"name":"Doe, John","group":"Red","age":{"v_0":24}}
    {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Green","age":{"v_0":31}}
    {"name":"Smith, Joan","group":"Yellow","age":{"v_0":22}}'
```

When I want to convert `json_file` to a data frame:

```
library(RJSONIO)
json_file <- fromJSON(json_file)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: parse error: trailing garbage
      :"Red","age":{"v_0":24}}     {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Gr
                 (right here) ------^
```

I know if I change the raw data to the following data, everything would be fine:

```
json_file <-  '[{"name":"Doe, John","group":"Red","age":{"v_0":24}},
    {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Green","age":{"v_0":31}},
    {"name":"Smith, Joan","group":"Yellow","age":{"v_0":22}}]'
```

But actually I would like to know:

1) How to get data frame from the raw data without splitting its objects using `[`, `,` and `]`?

2) If there is no way, how to split objects in a large `json` file by adding `,` to end of each line except the last line, and also adding `[` and `]` to the first and last line of the file?

Comment: Use `stream_in()`. See: https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/59

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705259/parsing-text-file-of-one-line-json-objects-using-rjsonio

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574842/read-jsons-in-r-to-data-frame

Answer (score 7):

There are ways to do it without the need to edit the file.

If you want a data.frame:

```
library(jsonlite)
# url
zips <- stream_in(url("http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json"))
# file
json_data <- stream_in(file("path/to/file.json"))
```

or if you want a list:

```
json_data_as_list <- readLines("path/to/file.json") %>% lapply(fromJSON)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your raw json data *is* already split into individual objects. On top of that, as a whole, the json data is invalid. Luckily, as you noticed, if you insert `,` at the end of each line (except the last) and wrap it all in square brackets, you get a collection of key-pairs (or arrays). So you should rather ask, "How do I combine all elements into a single data.frame?"

The solution: `dplyr::bind_rows(fromJSON(json_file))`

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name        group    age
  <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>
1 Doe, John   Red       24
2 Doe, Jane   Green     31
3 Smith, Joan Yellow    22
```

**Followup:**

Assuming the json objects **do not contain newlines**, you can do an easy search-replace:

```
json_file <- gsub('\n', ',', trimws(json_file), fixed=TRUE)
```

I put in the `trimws` to remove possible trailing newlines.

Next, you wrap it with square brackets:

```
json_file <- paste0('[', json_file, ']')
```

and you're back on track.

Comment: So, I have to insert `,` at the end of each line expect the last one and wrap the raw data  in square brackets manually? Now, what if I have a large `json` file?

Comment: Define "large".

Comment: When we have a lot of objects like 10000 objects.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue in R.

Answer (score -2):

You need those square brackets.  Save the following as 'test.json':

```
{ 
   "ID":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ],
   "Name":["Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary","Nina","Simon","Guru" ],
   "Salary":["623.3","515.2","611","729","843.25","578","632.8","722.5" ],

   "StartDate":[ "1/1/2012","9/23/2013","11/15/2014","5/11/2014","3/27/2015","5/21/2013",
      "7/30/2013","6/17/2014"],
   "Dept":[ "IT","Operations","IT","HR","Finance","IT","Operations","Finance"]
}
```

Now, load the required library and point to that file you just saved:

```
# Load the package required to read JSON files.
library("rjson")

# Give the input file name to the function.
result <- fromJSON(file = "C:\\Users\\Excel\\Documents\\test.json")

# Print the result.
print(result)
```

Result:

```
print(result)
$ID
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8"

$Name
[1] "Rick"     "Dan"      "Michelle" "Ryan"     "Gary"     "Nina"     "Simon"    "Guru"    

$Salary
[1] "623.3"  "515.2"  "611"    "729"    "843.25" "578"    "632.8"  "722.5" 

$StartDate
[1] "1/1/2012"   "9/23/2013"  "11/15/2014" "5/11/2014"  "3/27/2015"  "5/21/2013"  "7/30/2013"  "6/17/2014" 

$Dept
[1] "IT"         "Operations" "IT"         "HR"         "Finance"    "IT"         "Operations" "Finance"
```