# Update variables for each row in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, row, bioconductor

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
chr    alleles    position
2      [A/T]      123456
3      [C/T]      5678910
8      [A/G]      8765435334
```

I'd like to load each row into variables such as:

```
library('BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19')
chr <- 'chr2'
alleles <- '[T/C]'
position <- 123456
offset <- 60
```

and then use them iteratively in:

```
seq <- paste(getSeq(Hsapiens,chr,position-offset,position-1),
+              alleles,
+              getSeq(Hsapiens,chr,position+1,position+offset),
+              sep='')
```

and finally have the output as another dataframe containing:

```
chr    allele    position     seq
2      [A/T]      123456      "ACTTGGAGATTTGGAGGAAGCTCCAGAGAGAGAGAGGCTTCCCAGCGTGGACTTGAAAGA[A/T]GAAACCAGCATAGATAGCACCGTGAATGGTGAGTTGGAATTCCTGGTTTCACTTTTGTTA"
```

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699046/for-each-row-in-an-r-dataframe), but appreciate a solution that doesnt require indices!

Comment: Is `getSeq()` from a loaded package (in which case, which one?) or a function you've created (in which case could you add the source code for that function to your question)?

Comment: Also, is `Hsapiens` the name of your data frame?

Comment: @Phil Apologies for the confusion, yes getSeq is from the `BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19` library and `Hsapiens` is an attribute from the loaded packages.

Comment: Can you update your desired output to include some data in addition to the column names?

Comment: @seeellayewhy, thanks for your comment. I edited the result section!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using a [`map()`-type function](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) from purrr.

I don't have access to your `getSeq()` function or your `Hsapiens` data, but something like this should work if I understand your problem correctly.

```
# define helper function to simply syntax and make code readable
seq_extractor <- function(data, chr, position, alleles, offset=60){
    pre_seq <- getSeq(data, chr, position-offset, position-1)
    post_seq <- getSeq(data, chr, position+1, position+offset)
    paste(pre_seq, alleles, post_seq, sep='')
}

# use pmap_chr() to map your function onto your existing data
df %>%
    mutate(seq = pmap_chr(list(chr, alleles, position), 
                          ~seq_extractor(Hsapiens, ..1, ..3, ..2))
```