# Merging multiple columns in a dataframe based on condition in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R, and I want to do the following:

I have a data frame that consists of `ID, Col1, Col2, Col3` columns.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text="
ID Col1    Col2                        Col3             
1  0       'Less than once a month'    0               
2  Never   0                           0              
3  0       0                           'Once a month'
")
```

I want to merge those 3 columns into one, where if there is `"Never"` and `0` in the other columns the value is `"Never"`, if there is `"Once a month"` and the rest are `0`, then `"Once a month"` and so on. All columns are mutually exclusive meaning there cannot be `"Never"` and `"Once a month"` in the same raw.

```
 //I tried to apply this loop:

         for (val in df) {
if(df$Col1 == "Never" && df$Col2 == "0")
  {
  df$consolidated <- "Never"
  } else (df$`Col1 == "0" && df$Col2 == "Less than once a month")
  {
  how_oft_purch_gr_pers$consolidated <- "Less than once a month"
  }
}
```

I wanted to figure first for two columns only, but it didn't work, as all raws in the consolidated column are filled with "Less than once a month".

I want it to be like this:

```
ID Col1    Col2                       Col3             Consolidated
1  0       Less than once a month       0              Less than once a month
2  Never   0                            0              Never
3  0       0                            Once a month   Once a month
```

Any hint on what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you provide the desired output?

Comment: Your `df` has two rows with all three values in, and two with all zeros.

Comment: @Joe Dickens. First, you need to transform the dataframe and then you can apply your logic.

Comment: @Wimpel I have modified post, hope it will make more sense

Comment: @JoeDickens see my edit; it is very easy to reformat your code such that others can reproduce it easily `read.table(text = "...your data",...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of using `dplyr::coalesce` after replacing `0` with NA. The `coalesce()` finds the first non-missing value (in a row in this case) and creates a new column. The solution can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Col")), funs(na_if(.,"0"))) %>%
  mutate(Consolidated = coalesce(Col1,Col2,Col3)) %>%
  select(ID, Consolidated)

# OR in concise way once can simply write as
bind_cols(df[1], Consolidated = coalesce(!!!na_if(df[-1],"0")))

#   ID           Consolidated
# 1  1 Less than once a month
# 2  2                  Never
# 3  3           Once a month
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"ID Col1    Col2                       Col3             
1  0       'Less than once a month'       0               
2  Never   0                            0              
3  0       0                            'Once a month'",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple and efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

Even though @MKR has written a good answer, I want to point out a few errors in your code which might be the reason why it does not work

```
for (val in df) {
```

You problably want to loop over all rows of `df`. However, in fact you are looping over **columns** of your data frame. The reason is that a data frame is a list of vectors (your columns) which all must have the same length. With your code you iterate over the elements of `df`, which is the columns. See Q&A [**For each row in data.frame**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699046/for-each-row-in-an-r-dataframe)

```
  if(df$Col1 == "Never" && df$Col2 == "0"){
```

Note that when using the double `&&` instead of `&`, R is looking only at the first element of the vector you give it. See for example Q&A [**Boolean Operators && and ||**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and)

```
    df$consolidated <- "Never"
```

Here, you set the whole column `consolidated` of `df` to `"Never"`, because you do not use the iteration `var` from above (even if it would stand for one `df` row which it does not, like you wrote it).

```
  } else (df$`Col1 == "0" && df$Col2 == "Less than once a month"){
```

- You need to use `else if(...)`, not `else (...)`. Like you wrote it, R will think the statement in `(....)` should be executed if the `if(...)` above is not true and the statement in `{...}` after the if would be regarded by R as having nothing to do with the `if... else...` construct, because it already executed `(...)`. So it will execute the `{...}` block always, regardless of what is the outcome of the above `if(...)`.
- Is `` df$`Col1 `` a typo? The backtick `` ` `` should only occur in pairs and can be used around variables (also column names)

```
    df$consolidated <- "Less than once a month"
```

Here you again set a whole column to one value, like explained above.

```
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possiblity using base R

Start your result column. Initialize it with only `"0"`.

```
df$coalesced <- "0"
```

Loop over some columns of `df` (Col1--Col3). Use `drop = FALSE` in case you might only use one column, because R would output a vector in that case and for would loop over the elements of that vector and not over the single column in that case.

```
for( column in d[, c("Col1","Col2","Col3"), drop = FALSE]){
```

This checks each of `coalesced` if it is already filled, and if not (if it is `"0"` it fill  it with the current column (which may also be `"0"`)

```
    df$coalesced <- ifelse(df$coalesced == "0", column, df$coalesced)

}
```

Add the new column to your data frame

```
df$coalesced <- coalesced
```