# How to merge data frame columns based on value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to perform some analysis on the Online New Popularity dataset from the UCI Open Data Repo here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+news+popularity

The dataset has a set of 7 boolean attributes that denote the day of the week that the article was published on. For example, the column `weekday_is_monday` will have the value `1` if the article was published on a Monday and so on. For my analysis, I am trying to merge these fields into a single field that contains the string literal of publishing day.

So I load this dataset then go through and replace each true value with the string literal:

```r
news <- read.csv("path_to_my_dataset",
                 header=TRUE,
                 sep=",",
                 fill=F,
                 strip.white = T,
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
news$weekday_is_monday <- gsub('^1', 'Monday', news$weekday_is_monday)
news$weekday_is_tuesday <- gsub('^1', 'Tuesday', news$weekday_is_tuesday)
news$weekday_is_wednesday <- gsub('^1', 'Wednesday', news$weekday_is_wednesday)
news$weekday_is_thursday <- gsub('^1', 'Thusday', news$weekday_is_thursday)
news$weekday_is_friday <- gsub('^1', 'Friday', news$weekday_is_friday)
news$weekday_is_saturday <- gsub('^1', 'Saturday', news$weekday_is_saturday)
news$weekday_is_sunday <- gsub('^1', 'Sunday', news$weekday_is_sunday)
```

Next I found a solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874955/merging-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe-based-on-condition-in-r) that used the `dpyler::coalesce` function to merge all the fields. I adapted this to my dataset as follows:

```r
news <- news %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("weekday_is")), funs(na_if(.,"0"))) %>%
  mutate(news, publishing_day = coalesce(weekday_is_monday, weekday_is_tuesday, weekday_is_wednesday, weekday_is_thursday,
                                   weekday_is_friday, weekday_is_saturday, weekday_is_sunday))
news$publishing_day <- as.factor(news$publishing_day)
summary(news$publishing_day)
```

However, this only merges the fields from the first column (i.e. Monday):

```
     0 Monday 
 32983   6661
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pipe operation, do not repeat inputting the data on the left hand side of `mutate` into the right hand side of it. That is the cause of your problem. You just need to remove `news` in `mutate(news, publishing_day = ...)`

```
news <- news %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("weekday_is")), funs(na_if(.,"0"))) %>%
  mutate(publishing_day = coalesce(weekday_is_monday, weekday_is_tuesday, weekday_is_wednesday, weekday_is_thursday,
                                         weekday_is_friday, weekday_is_saturday, weekday_is_sunday))
news$publishing_day <- as.factor(news$publishing_day)
summary(news$publishing_day)
#  Friday    Monday  Saturday    Sunday   Thusday   Tuesday Wednesday 
#    5701      6661      2453      2737      7267      7390      7435
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one technique that uses reshaping `pivot_longer`, then `gsub` the literal out of the `weekday_` column, then joining it back in.

```r
quux <- read.csv("OnlineNewsPopularity.csv") # from your link

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
quux2 <- quux %>%
  select(url, starts_with("weekday_is")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-url) %>%
  dplyr::filter(value > 0) %>%
  mutate(weekday = gsub("weekday_is_", "", name)) %>%
  left_join(quux, by = "url") %>%
  select(-name, -starts_with("weekday_is_"))
quux2
# # A tibble: 39,644 x 56
#    url          value weekday timedelta n_tokens_title n_tokens_content n_unique_tokens n_non_stop_words n_non_stop_uniq~ num_hrefs
#    <chr>        <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1 http://mash~     1 monday        731             12              219           0.664             1.00            0.815         4
#  2 http://mash~     1 monday        731              9              255           0.605             1.00            0.792         3
#  3 http://mash~     1 monday        731              9              211           0.575             1.00            0.664         3
#  4 http://mash~     1 monday        731              9              531           0.504             1.00            0.666         9
#  5 http://mash~     1 monday        731             13             1072           0.416             1.00            0.541        19
#  6 http://mash~     1 monday        731             10              370           0.560             1.00            0.698         2
#  7 http://mash~     1 monday        731              8              960           0.418             1.00            0.550        21
#  8 http://mash~     1 monday        731             12              989           0.434             1.00            0.572        20
#  9 http://mash~     1 monday        731             11               97           0.670             1.00            0.837         2
# 10 http://mash~     1 monday        731             10              231           0.636             1.00            0.797         4
# # ... with 39,634 more rows, and 46 more variables: num_self_hrefs <dbl>, num_imgs <dbl>, num_videos <dbl>,
# #   average_token_length <dbl>, num_keywords <dbl>, data_channel_is_lifestyle <dbl>, data_channel_is_entertainment <dbl>,
# #   data_channel_is_bus <dbl>, data_channel_is_socmed <dbl>, data_channel_is_tech <dbl>, data_channel_is_world <dbl>,
# #   kw_min_min <dbl>, kw_max_min <dbl>, kw_avg_min <dbl>, kw_min_max <dbl>, kw_max_max <dbl>, kw_avg_max <dbl>, kw_min_avg <dbl>,
# #   kw_max_avg <dbl>, kw_avg_avg <dbl>, self_reference_min_shares <dbl>, self_reference_max_shares <dbl>,
# #   self_reference_avg_sharess <dbl>, is_weekend <dbl>, LDA_00 <dbl>, LDA_01 <dbl>, LDA_02 <dbl>, LDA_03 <dbl>, LDA_04 <dbl>,
# #   global_subjectivity <dbl>, global_sentiment_polarity <dbl>, global_rate_positive_words <dbl>, ...
```

Proof of contents:

```r
table(quux2$weekday)
#    friday    monday  saturday    sunday  thursday   tuesday wednesday 
#      5701      6661      2453      2737      7267      7390      7435
```

You might consider converting that into a `factor` if you intend to ever `arrange` on the `weekday`, since otherwise it'll sort them lexicographically (as shown above).

```r
... %>%
  mutate(weekday = factor(weekday, levels = c("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", ..., "sunday")))
```

FYI, the only reason I assigned the pipe from `quux` into a new variable `quux2` was so that during your testing and evaluation of this, you would not inadvertently irreversibly overwrite your main dataset. Feel free to overwrite back onto itself.

Comment: The accepted answer to this post found the issue in my code, but this is probably a more reliable (and definitely tidier) method of doing it than my mess! Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, different approaches help viewing the problem differently. Glad you got the fix you needed!