# Iterating function over every row in data frame in R

Tags: r, function

So I have a function `flip.allele(a, b, c, d)` which takes in 4 arguments and then returns a numerical value based on comparing these different arguments. I am now trying to write an additional function which will take this function and then apply it to a whole data frame, so iterate my the original function across every row in the data frame.

So the four values I want to compare are in columns 2, 3, 4, 5. And I want it to output the value of comparing those four columns into a new column 6.

This is my current attempt at doing this:

```
flip.data.frame = function(df) {

  for (i in nrow(df)) {

    df$flip = flip.allele(df[2], df[3], df[4], df[5])
  }
}
```

The issue is that all of my attempts so far (including this one) have meant that when trying to use it on my data, it takes the first 4 values, correctly applies the `flip.allele` function and then returns the value for that row into every single row in the data frame.

I know that this is because of the way I'm using the `df$flip =` bit, but I'm also not sure what a solution would be. I saw [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699046/for-each-row-in-an-r-dataframe) which seemed to suggest using `apply()` but I'm not completely certain how to go about using that.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`.

```
apply(df[2:5], 1, function(x) flip.allele(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]))
```

---

Or using `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap(setnames(df[2:5], letters[1:4]), flip.allele)
```

Comment: For the former possibility should it be as you've written it or did you mean it should be:
```apply(df[2:5], 1, flip.allele(df) flip.allele(df[1], df[2], df[3], df[4]))```
If it is as you've written it, then I'm not completely sure what the ```function(x)``` part of that is doing, could you possibly explain it?
Similarly, what exactly is ```pmap``` doing?

Comment: @Sabor117 according to your description in the post, you want to apply the function for each row. using the values of the columns.  The `apply`, is doing that.  It loops through the row of the columns 2:5 and apply the `flip.allele` function