# Improve coding -- using tidyverse to compute confidence intervals (for proportions) and add the results to individual rows

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, confidence-interval

I'm here again to ask the colleagues to help me to improve this code. Since this forum is so receptive, I would like to hear your thoughts about this situation!

The question is pretty simple but needs knowledge about looping / for() / by() etc and I'm almost autodidact when programming in R:

I'm working on a dataset where I have estimates for **proprtions** and I want to compute the **lower** and **upper** boundaries for the confidence interval. The work consists of transforming this:

[image: Original dataset]

to this:

[image]

There is a package that computes that for me

> library(PropCIs)

The solution was intuitive *(for me)*. 
1) Get every point estimate,
2) compute its lower and upper boundaries and
3) move to the next row and
4) Return to the first step.

My workaround was based on [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699046/for-each-row-in-an-r-dataframe) and is described below step by step. However, I imagine this solution is too slow, naive or works like I'm talking with a strange accent to any native data scientist. Then, I'm wondering if *tidyverse* could help me to improve that.

```
library(PropCIs)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(estimate = runif(15, min=0, max=1), 
                 sample = sample(x = 10:15, 15, replace = T))

ds <- ds %>% mutate(lower = '')  

#looping
for(i in 1:nrow(ds)) { 
  ds$lower[i] <- blakerci(ds$sample[i], 3449, conf.level=0.95)
}

#row to columns
ds <- separate(data = ds, col = lower, into = c("lower", "upper"), sep = ",")

#replace strings
ds <- ds %>% mutate(lower = gsub("c(", "", lower, fixed = TRUE),
                  upper = gsub(")", "", upper, fixed = TRUE))

#Transform to numeric
ds <- ds %>% mutate_at(vars(lower, upper), funs(as.numeric(.)))
```

As always, thanks much for all support!

Please take into consideration this post has a reproducible script and can help other people! =)

Comment: This seems like it might be a better question for [codereview.se] There's not really a specific programming question here. Otherwise be more specific about what exactly needs to change. What exactly are you trying to fix?

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick. Actually, is not a programming question, but I question to help me to improve this code using tidyverse family if possible. I did not know about the Code Review section!!! I'll move this question to there !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `PropCIs` before, but it seems cool to think in probability.
Here is the code in `tidyverse` style.

```r
library(PropCIs)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> 载入程辑包：'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose
set.seed(123)
data.table(
    # data.table is faster.
    estimate = runif(15, min=0, max=1)
    ,sample = sample(x = 10:15, 15, replace = T)
) %>% 
    mutate(
        ci = map(sample
                    ,~blakerci(., 3449, conf.level=0.95) %>% 
                    .$conf.int %>% 
                    .[1:2]
                    # get lower and upper
                    )
        # why n = 3449? Any assumption?
    ) %>% 
    mutate(
        lower = map_dbl(ci,~.[1])
        ,upper = map_dbl(ci,~.[2])
    ) %>% 
    select(-ci)
#>     estimate sample       lower       upper
#> 1  0.2875775     15 0.002476132 0.007123028
#> 2  0.7883051     11 0.001593144 0.005669411
#> 3  0.4089769     10 0.001481219 0.005245599
#> 4  0.8830174     11 0.001593144 0.005669411
#> 5  0.9404673     15 0.002476132 0.007123028
#> 6  0.0455565     15 0.002476132 0.007123028
#> 7  0.5281055     14 0.002350896 0.006691190
#> 8  0.8924190     13 0.002038424 0.006396837
#> 9  0.5514350     15 0.002476132 0.007123028
#> 10 0.4566147     13 0.002038424 0.006396837
#> 11 0.9568333     14 0.002350896 0.006691190
#> 12 0.4533342     13 0.002038424 0.006396837
#> 13 0.6775706     13 0.002038424 0.006396837
#> 14 0.5726334     11 0.001593144 0.005669411
#> 15 0.1029247     10 0.001481219 0.005245599
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  zh_CN.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Asia/Shanghai               
#>  date     2018-11-07
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version date       source         
#>  assertthat   0.2.0   2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  backports    1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  base       * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  bindr        0.1.1   2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  bindrcpp   * 0.2.2   2018-03-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  broom        0.5.0   2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  cellranger   1.1.0   2016-07-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  cli          1.0.0   2017-11-05 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  colorspace   1.3-2   2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  compiler     3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  crayon       1.3.4   2017-09-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  data.table * 1.11.8  2018-09-30 cran (@1.11.8) 
#>  datasets   * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  devtools     1.13.6  2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  digest       0.6.16  2018-08-22 cran (@0.6.16) 
#>  dplyr      * 0.7.6   2018-06-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1) 
#>  evaluate     0.11    2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  forcats    * 0.3.0   2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  ggplot2    * 3.0.0   2018-07-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  glue         1.3.0   2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  graphics   * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  grDevices  * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  grid         3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  gtable       0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  haven        1.1.2   2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  hms          0.4.2   2018-03-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  htmltools    0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  httr         1.3.1   2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  jsonlite     1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  knitr        1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  lattice      0.20-35 2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1) 
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  lubridate    1.7.4   2018-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  magrittr     1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  memoise      1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  methods    * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  modelr       0.1.2   2018-05-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  munsell      0.5.0   2018-06-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  nlme         3.1-137 2018-04-07 CRAN (R 3.5.1) 
#>  pillar       1.3.0   2018-07-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  pkgconfig    2.0.1   2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  plyr         1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  PropCIs    * 0.3-0   2018-02-23 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  purrr      * 0.2.5   2018-05-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  R6           2.3.0   2018-10-04 cran (@2.3.0)  
#>  Rcpp         0.12.19 2018-10-01 cran (@0.12.19)
#>  readr      * 1.1.1   2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  readxl       1.1.0   2018-04-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  rlang        0.2.2   2018-08-16 cran (@0.2.2)  
#>  rmarkdown    1.10    2018-06-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  rprojroot    1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  rvest        0.3.2   2016-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  scales       1.0.0   2018-08-09 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  stats      * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  stringi      1.2.4   2018-07-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  stringr    * 1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tibble     * 1.4.2   2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tidyr      * 0.8.1   2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tidyselect   0.2.5   2018-10-11 cran (@0.2.5)  
#>  tidyverse  * 1.2.1   2017-11-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tools        3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  utils      * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  withr        2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  xml2         1.2.0   2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  yaml         2.2.0   2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
```

Comment: Awesome. This solution was pretty elegant and much more understandable when compared to mine. 10/10!!  (n = 3449 was a previous assumption I forgot to mention)